# How to perform LIKE query with spaces

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Hello guys I'm trying to find all the results from multiple columns based on the search string through query params. If I add any values with space then the query fails and returns empty array. This is what I have done -

```
    const queryBuilder = this._usersRepository
          .createQueryBuilder('user')
          .select()
          .where('user.first_name LIKE :first_name', {
               first_name: `%${pageOptionsQuery.search_term}%`,
           })
           .orWhere('user.last_name LIKE :last_name', {
               last_name: `%${pageOptionsQuery.search_term}%`,
           })
           .orWhere('user.email LIKE :email', {
                email: `%${pageOptionsQuery.search_term}%`,
           });


     const [users, count] = await Promise.all([
            await queryBuilder
                .take(pageOptionsQuery.limit)
                .skip(pageOptionsQuery.skip)
                .getMany(),
            await this.getUsersCount(),
     ]);
```

In the search term if use only 'john' then I am getting results but if adds any space 'john julie' then the query not working. Can somebody help me out thanks?

Comment: So are you using MySQL or Postgres? Remove the tag of the one you aren't using.

Comment: I am using postgres

Comment: 1) Have you tried the query in `psql` to see if works? In other words are there actually values like  'john julie', with the exact amount of space between words? 2) Can you  see what ``%${pageOptionsQuery.search_term}%`` actually resolves to? 3) Are the strings in the database mixed case? If so have you tried `ILIKE`?  Add answers as update to question.

Comment: Can you enable logs to typeorm config (‘all’) and see the query output?

Comment: What you mean by query fails? Is there error or just empty array?  Have you checked with ‘ilike’ operator?